# Executing .cmd file on remote machine using WMI

Tags: cmd, wmi, remote-access, rpc, windows-networking

I need to execute a .cmd file on a remote machine using WMIC, I can't use ssh-power shell.
I tried executing the code below
and following was printed on console:

`C:\>WMIC/node:"remote-server01" process call create "cmd.exe /c C:\test.cmd"`

```
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

However nothing is executed on remote machine.

Comment: Why is there a _space_ between `C:\` and `test.cmd` in your code?

Comment: its C:\test.cmd - no space in between, typing error

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is executed in the remote machine because the process creation failed with a *"Path not found"* error as stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **Return value**
>
> Returns a value of 0 (zero) if the process was successfully created,
>   and any other number to indicate an error. For additional error codes,
>   see WMI Error Constants or WbemErrorEnum. For general HRESULT values,
>   see System Error Codes.
>
> Successful completion (0)
>   Access denied (2)
>   Insufficient privilege (3)
>   Unknown failure (8)
>   **Path not found (9)**
>   Invalid parameter (21)
>   Other (22–4294967295)

The *"Method execution successful"* refers to the call to the method, not to the process creation.

Comment: I tried to fix it and now it is llike Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 7984;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};

Still nothing executes on remote machine
C:\Users\tiwaris>

Comment: @aquesh, If you have a ProcessId, the process was started. Try to run `tasklist /fi "pid eq 7984"` (your process id). If the process is present, it is probably running in a separate session. If it is not pressent, probably it has ended.

Comment: It says no task running :(

Comment: Do you have any approach on how I can call a cmd file residing on remote machine, other than using ssh, I need to execute it using commandline only somehow

Comment: @aquesh, If you got a process id, at least the `cmd.exe` was started. Try to run a batch file that simply contains `pause` to force it to wait and test again. You can use `psexec` from the Microsoft Sysinternals tools, but you will have to download it from Microsoft. Anyway WMI should work.

Comment: on using pause, in front of the command in bat file, Now i can see the process getting created as cmd.exe,C:\Users\tiwaris>tasklist /fi "pid eq 5388"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
cmd.exe                       5388 Services                   0      3,616 K

Comment: Still the command that i had writtern in .bat file(is not reflected), am I missing something.The command in bat file that I am trying to execute is a postjava command

Comment: @aquesh, Now you know the wmic command, authentication, process creation, ... is correct. You will need to test the commands you are running inside your batch file and be sure they are executed. Try to retrieve and send information to a log file after each command. Think you are running the command in a separate session.